# creating conditions for recieving partial delivery of products in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, if-statement, conditional-statements

Its my 2nd day of trying to make my "receiving of partial delivery" for my app. I am trying my luck here with you masters.

I have these two tables, the first one is the **order_items** table,

[image]

This table holds the items from the purchase order. and the other table is **warehouse1**

[image]

which hold the partially receive items.

I get the logic, I have to group the **warehouse1.order_item_id** so that I could get the sum of the items from let say **order_number_id=22** which is the id from **order_items** table. to show you, here's my code doing the GROUP

```
public function viewdeliveryItems($id)
{
    $partialDeliveries = Warehouse1stocks::where('order_id', '=', $id)
       ->select(
                'order_item_id',
                DB::raw('SUM(stock_in_qty) as stock_in_qty'))->groupBy('order_item_id')->get();
                // DB::raw('SUM(stock_out_qty) as stock_out_qty'))->groupBy('order_item_id')->get();


    $order = Orders::find($id);
    $orderItems = $order->orderItems;


    $warehouse1stocks = Warehouse1stocks::all('order_id','order_item_id','stock_in_qty')->where('order_id','=',$id);

    return view('orders.delivery')->with('order', $order)
                                  ->with('warehouse1stocks', $warehouse1stocks)
                                  ->with('partialDeliveries', $partialDeliveries);
}
```

in my code you'll see that I group the **order_item_id** and called also the **order items** but you can see that their only link is **ORDER_ID**.

Just to show you the eloquent connection,
**in Orderitems Model**

```
public function Warehouse1stocks()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Warehouse1stocks', 'id', 'order_item_id')->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC');
}
```

**Warehouse1stocks model**

```
public function orderItems()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Orderitems', 'order_id', 'id')->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC');

}
```

**And in my blade**, as I mention in my intro, I am doing this in almost 2 days now, I'm just starting to write my own code that's why I am relying most of my codes base from tutorials and suggestions available on google, I think I tried too many approaches already and due to desperation I end up with this,

```
@foreach($order->orderItems as $key=>$orderItem)
<tr>
    <td>{{ $orderItem->product_code }}</td>
    <td>{{ $orderItem->product_name }}</td>

    <td>
    @foreach($partialDeliveries as $partialDelivery)

            @if($partialDelivery->order_item_id == $orderItem->id)
                @php
                $remainingDeliveries = $orderItem->quantity - $partialDelivery->stock_in_qty;
                @endphp                    
            @else
                @php
                $remainingDeliveries = $orderItem->quantity;
                @endphp
            @endif


                {!! Form::number('stock_in_qty[]', $remainingDeliveries, 
                                ['id'=>'stock_in_qty_'.$orderItem->id]) !!} 
    @endforeach
    </td>
    ....
</tr>
@endforeach
```

**note: at first it has " @if($loop->first)" right below of the first ForEach. I just remove it.

**Explanation**
the first @foreach calls the items from orderItems table and the second calls the item which has the (sum)quantity of **partially received items**

from my if condition, if both order_item_id are equal then triggers the computation. if not then just grab the quantity from order_items table.

But doing this does not gave what my expected result should be.

To give you an idea here's the screenshot of my blade,

[image]

I know my post is too long but I guess I need to explain more so that hopefully you could understand the scenario.

Masters, I am really hoping you can help me with this. Thank you so much in advance!!!

**UPDATE (solved)**

upon digging a little more dipper, and removing and adding some codes and most importantly after following @Watercayman's answer, I finally solve it. for others who's also facing same issue as mine, here's what I did.

```
@if (isset($partialDeliveries[$key]))
    @foreach($partialDeliveries as $partialDelivery)
        @if($partialDelivery->order_item_id == $orderItem->id)
            @php
                $remainingDeliveries = $orderItem->quantity - $partialDelivery->stock_in_qty;
            @endphp
        @endif
    @endforeach
@endif
@if (!isset($partialDeliveries[$key]))
    @php
        $remainingDeliveries = $orderItem->quantity;
    @endphp
@endif
```

I can't explain everything because simply i can't :)

Thanks @Watercatman!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are asking why the quantity on your quantity column is not giving you a form, or why the return from that input is not correct, you have a few problems that I can see.  The first issue is that you are creating n+1 number of number input form items **in the same space with the same ID**.  This will likely prevent them from showing up, and will never produce a usable form.  This:

```
{!! Form::number('stock_in_qty[]', $remainingDeliveries, 
                            ['id'=>'stock_in_qty_'.$orderItem->id]) !!}
```

is inside your inner for-loop.  So for every `$partialDelivery` within that loop, you are creating multiple number inputs with the exact same id (`'stock_in_qty_'.$orderItem->id`).

I can't speak for the sql, as I dont' know know what's dumping, but it would really help you to do the calculations for `$remainingDeliveries` back in your controller.  Looping inside the larger `<tr>` loop is probably not the easiest way to get your calculation correctly or cleanly.  But, if you must do it in the blade file, *move the number input outside the @foreach loop* so that you have exactly one input with one id.

Comment: You're correct @Watercayman. I just move the number field outside the loop. But what I still facing right now is that if the condition is not equal the "remainingDeliveries" variable is being undefined...